# Curl to upload a zip file with rowdata

Tags: curl

Want to try page form fill with file upload . [image]

When execute F12 i saw url also  below part

-----------------------------424134892007
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="mstore-yangFiles.zip"
Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed

PK

-----------------------------424134892007
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rowData"

{"id":"","name":"tt","namespace":"","nsdId":"mStore_NSD","vnfdId":"mStore_VNFD","vduId":"mStore-VDU","filePath":"mstore-yangFiles.zip","uploadDatetime":""}
-----------------------------424134892007--

How to set above thing in Curl ?

```
enter code here
```

curl --verbose --header  -F name=file -F filename=@mstore-yangFiles.zip -F name=tt -F nsdId=mStore_NSD -F vnfdId=mStore_VNFD -F vduId=mStore-VDU -F filePath=@mstore-yangFiles.zip http://10.10.149.9:18080/cms-service/webapi/data/data_model

used the command with Content-Type.Response get

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 400 
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 29 Mar 2017 13:41:19 GMT
Connection: close

curl -v -X POST -F file=@mstore-yangFiles.tar.gz -F rowData='{"id":"","name":"tt","namespace":"","nsdId":"mStore_NSD","vnfdId":"mStore_VNFD","vduId":"mStore-VDU","filePath":"mstore-yangFiles.zip","uploadDatetime":""}'  http://10.10.149.7:18080/cms-service/webapi/data/data_model

Only after changing file extension to tar.gz it worked as in case of zip content-type was formed wrong.

Comment: I did part but somthing i am missing.                                                   curl --verbose --header "Content-Type: application/zip" --data-binary @mstore-yangFiles.zip http://10.10.149.7:18080/cms-service/webapi/data/data_model -d 'rowData={"id":"","name":"tt","namespace":"","nsdId":"mStore_NSD","vnfdId":"mStore_VNFD","vduId":"mStore-VDU","filePath":"mstore-yangFiles.zip","uploadDatetime":""}'

Comment: i changed curl --verbose --header "Content-Type: application/zip" -d 'rowData={"id":"","name":"tt","namespace":"","nsdId":"mStore_NSD","vnfdId":"mStore_VNFD","vduId":"mStore-VDU","filePath":"mstore-yangFiles.zip","uploadDatetime":""}'  http://10.10.149.7:18080/cms-service/webapi/data/data_model to curl --verbose --header "Content-Type: application/zip" -F name=file -F filename=@mstore-yangFiles.zip -F name=tt -F nsdId=mStore_NSD -F vnfdId=mStore_VNFD -F vduId=mStore-VDU -F filePath=@mstore-yangFiles.zip http://10.10.149.9:18080/cms-service/webapi/data/data_model ..same response HTTP/1.1 415

Comment: if i remove Content-Type: then getting 400 response

Comment: curl -v -X POST -F file=@mstore-yangFiles.tar.gz -F rowData='{"id":"","name":"tt","namespace":"","nsdId":"mStore_NSD","vnfdId":"mStore_VNFD","vduId":"mStore-VDU","filePath":"mstore-yangFiles.zip","uploadDatetime":""}'  http://10.10.149.7:18080/cms-service/webapi/data/data_model